# Dismissing keyboard when user taps outside of UITextField

Tags: ios, scope, uitextfield, swift4, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following code for dismissing the keyboard when a user taps outside of the text field

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

The selector function is the following:

```
@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

The first bit of code is in the viewDidLoad, which is what my question is about. Why doesn't it work if:
`let tap UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))` is done outside of the viewDidLoad() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self` can't be accessed like what you want it to , you can use a `lazy var` like this outside of any method inside the VC

```
lazy var tap = { 
    return UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
}()
```

Comment: Thanks! what is about the `{}()` that allows the self property to work as expected?

Comment: @Sh_Khan or someone else please answer the above question.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html